# codeigniter $this dont load in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a problem im trying to deal with for a long time,

i have a codeigniter webapp that im building and i have a problem with the $this of codeigniter

i will show you with so examples:

this is in my controller

```
$this->site_model->blog_post('title');
```

this one work perfectly /\

if im loading an other / different  model it will load it all good, but if im calling a function in the new model like this:

```
$this->Admin_model->blog_post('title');
```

it will give me this

```
Undefined property: Idx::$Admin_model

Call to a member function get_categories() on a non-object in   

C:\dev\wamp\www\francebeautycoil\application\controllers\idx.php on line 22
```

if im doing the next code

```
public $ci = '';

$this->ci =& get_instance(); 

$this->load->model('Admin_model');

$this->ci->Admin_model->blog_post('title');
```

it will work.

ive tryed all the catital lettes, lowercase letters.

the thing is that its append not only on this model but on few libraries too.

please help, im stuck.

Comment: Did create a constructor in your controller?

Comment: You just need to load the model before you using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you use an model you need to load it first , on second snipped you need to load Admin_model first

```
if im loading an other / different model
```

On second snppiet you are calling a method on Admin_model not  loading it on line below

```
$this->Admin_model->blog_post('title');
```

so load it first

```
$this->load->model('Admin_model');
```

so it becomes

```
$this->load->model('Admin_model');
$this->Admin_model->blog_post('title');
```

Comment: this is not the problem, im loading it first but still it doesnt recognize the $this->modelName as an object only if i do $this->ci->modelName after i load it first of cours